# Segments are displaying with blue colour instead of images in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode

I created segments in Xcode 4.6 and I am trying to update my project to iOS 7 but segments are showing up with blue icons instead of represented images. Please help with any suggestions.

Comment: More information please.  What kind of segments?  What images are you trying to show?  How are you showing them?  ...?

Comment: for each index iam adding customised image instead of default